# What is the cheapest 20mm-diameter roll-angle-sensor (+/-10deg, 60Hz update) you have come across?

Tags: mobile-robot

What is the cheapest roll-angle-sensor (10degree accuracy, 60Hz update) you have come across for airborne
mobile robots that have a 20mm diameter, shaped like a rocket?  (The robot
is shaped like a rocket and one may need to fit a roll sensor inside of it.)
   I realize that for purely vertical travel, some type of compass would work, but the robot here needs to be able to travel horizontally as well as vertically.  This one below at inertiallabs.com is 554dollars.  I am hoping to find cheaper:
https://inertiallabs.com/os3d.html
Buy here for 554dollars:
https://ozrobotics.com/shop/sub-miniature-3d-orientation-sensor-os3dm/

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* robotmore, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: As [FooBar said](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/19483/9720), sensors are available that range from essentially a guess to the degree of precision required for space applications. You should put limits on what amount of error is acceptable for your application. Once you do that, you can search a site like [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/sensors-transducers/motion-sensors-imus-inertial-measurement-units/567?stock=1) and filter down the results to what is acceptable, then sort by price.

Comment: Chuck, can you suggest an alternate forum for "shopping questions"?

Comment: Foobar, I think mpu-9255 may be out of stock.  But it looks like these parts at digikey may work:  828-1089-1-nd and 828-1044-1-nd  I had no idea it could be done so cheap, totaling $12. (!?)  That is a huge relief!!!!!!

Comment: You're *always* welcome to ask off-topic questions in [chat] when you have the [privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). Regarding the MPU9255, [the English version of the page FooBar linked](https://www.watterott.com/en/9-DOF-IMU-Module-With-MPU-9250) shows 4 in in stock, and [Amazon has the same product available](https://www.amazon.com/UCTRONICS-MPU-9255-compass-Accelerometer-Gyroscope/dp/B01DIGRR8U) with 12 in stock.

Comment: Asimov's Corner doesn't seem to be used much since the last post was 56days ago (even I were able to get the 'privilege').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking for the cheapest sensor does not make much sense without specifying a maximal error. Otherwise I propose to add a small rock, guess a zero-roll angle and you have a 'sensor' for free with a maximal error of 180deg.

A real solution would rather be any IMU with a magnetometer (like the [MPU9255](https://www.watterott.com/index.php?page=product&info=4719)). It's around 10$ and would give you the information you need.